# Duplicate Identifier Error in Visual Studio Code w/ Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, angular

I'm trying to set up a component in Angular 2 with Typescript using Visual Studio Code for Mac. When I use the following code, I get these errors: `duplicate identifier 'Component'.` and `Duplicate identifier' DashboardComponent'.`

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'dashboard',
   templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'
})

export class DashboardComponent {

}
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
app
-dashboard
--dashboard.component.html
--dashboard.component.ts
-app.component.html
-app.component.ts
-main.ts
index.html
```

I'm not exporting the class `DashboardComponent` anywhere else in the code.

I'm not sure if this is a Visual Studio Code issue or a Typescript/Angular2 issue. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Paste your tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The common reason for such problems is that you do have that identifier exported several times in your project (that is everything under project root dir) somewhere in d.ts files deep nested in folder structure. To eliminate such error the usual route is to exclude 'node_modules' and (if you use typings) 'browser' or 'main' typings folder leaving just one. That is done by using "exclude" section of tsconfig.json. Having said that the typical tsconfig will look something like this:

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": { 
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser/**"
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.